# select year(getdate() -2) and month as 12

Tags: sql, sql-server

my source table column is `ReportingPeriod Nvarchar(6)`
delete query has to be for datas before 2 years.

this query does not work

```
delete from table where ReportingPeriod  < year(getdate() -2) and month as 12
```

I need to get 201212 as result

the criteria is current year -2 and month is 12

in 2014 expected result is 201212
in 2015 expected result is 201312

Comment: convert ReportingPeriod  clumn into datetime with your format then continue your's work

Answer (score 1):

I would do all of the date maths first keeping things as `datetime` and then convert to `nvarchar` at the end. Handily, `CONVERT` will just truncate the result if not enough space is provided, so we just provide space for the year and month and we get what we want:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(6),
      DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                                ,'19991201')
   ,112)
```

Result:

```
201212
```

This works because we exploit the relationship between two arbitrary dates - for instance, for any date in 2001, the result we would want would be a date in december 1999 - so that's what I've used.

---

It's true that the above may look overly complex for this requirement, but it's possible to make a great many problems fit the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pattern with the appropriate choice of the period to use and the two arbitrary dates and the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
WHERE ReportingPeriod < Convert(nvarchar(4), year(getdate()) - 2) + '12'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your `ReportingPeriod` to a date, so `201212` would become `2012-12-01` as I assume you aren't concerned with the day of the month.

```
cast(left(ReportingPeriod,4) + '-' 
    + RIGHT(ReportingPeriod, 2) + '-01' as datetime)
```

Then take the current year -2 from `GETDATE()` and append the month `12` and day `31` to compare these values against, which would return `2012-12-31`.

```
cast(cast(
     cast(year(getdate()) -2 as nvarchar(4))
     + '-12-31' as nvarchar(10)) as datetime)
```

So combining these you should be able to select all records older than 2 years, based on the month being set to `12`.

```
select cast(left(ReportingPeriod,4) + '-' 
       + RIGHT(ReportingPeriod, 2) + '-01' as datetime) ReportPeriodDate
from [YourTable]
where cast(left(ReportingPeriod,4) + '-' 
      + RIGHT(ReportingPeriod, 2) + '-01' as datetime) 
      <= cast(cast(
              cast(year(getdate()) -2 as nvarchar(4)) 
+ '-12-31' as nvarchar(10)) as datetime)
```

Then you just need to delete with this logic.

```
delete [YourTable]
where cast(left(ReportingPeriod,4) + '-' 
      + RIGHT(ReportingPeriod, 2) + '-01' as datetime) 
      <= cast(cast(
              cast(year(getdate()) -2 as nvarchar(4)) 
              + '-12-31' as nvarchar(10)) as datetime)
```

### [Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e1df/1)